# Qt 5.2 & iOS: "Nothing to be done"

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qt-creator

I am currently trying to get a simple widget based "hello world" iOS application getting built with "Qt 5.2 for iOS". However, when using QtCreator to compile a freshly created test application with the `iphonesimulator-clang kit` it just says "there is nothing to be done for first", and no binary file is created. I have spent a few hours already to track this down, but can't figure out what I have configured wrong.

I am using a MacBook Air with OS X 10.8.5, Qt 5.2.0, `QtCreator 3.0.`0 and `XCode 5.0.2` (in case this matters). There is also Qt 4.8.5 installed on this machine, this this version is what I used for production purposes.

Some more things to mention:

- When running qmake from QtCreator it gives a warning "`The version of XCode installed on this system is not recognized`"
- The iOS sample applications shipped with 5.2 do build and run correctly
- When deleting the ".pro.user" file of such a shipped sample, which means that I need to reconfigure the project in QtCreator again afterwards (selecting the kit), the sample shows the same problems as my freshly created test app: qmake will warn about the `XCode` version and the make step will not do anything.

Any hints are more than welcome!

Comment: I have figured out that I need to add xcodebuild as an additional build step for some reason. This causes the files to get compiled. However, linking fails since it tries to link against the device libs (ios/lib/libQt5Gui_debug.a) instead of the simulator libs (ios/lib/libQt5Gui_simulator_debug.a). Any hint how I can fix this?

Comment: I deleted and reinstalled Qt 5.2.0 for iOS, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case other people run into the same problem - I finally tracked it down:
**Installing the latest XCode command line tools solved the problem**.

When initially installing "Qt 5.2 for iOS" I also updated to the latest XCode version via the App Store. I guess that the XCode update did not update the command line tools (which I already had installed before), and for some reason Qt did then silently fail on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Qt 5.2 on my Macbook Pro to do the same as you try to do, a simple qt widget based "Hello World" for iOS and it just works fine.
Build for simulator and run in simulator works on my first try, no need for me to add any extra build step or anything, just using the project template for a widget based iOS application and adding a label.

I see some differences between our setups, but cannot say if any of them are the one causing problems for you: 
I have OS X 10.9.1, Qt 5.2.0 for both iOS and Android.

The other versions are the same: QtCreator 3.0 and Xcode 5.0.2.

Hopefully this can be of some help.

See image of iOS simulator running Qt Hello World at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko4xy.png

Compiler output from a "build project" after a "clean project":

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.DebugSimulator
Build settings from command line:
SDKROOT = iphonesimulator7.0

=== BUILD AGGREGATE TARGET Qt Preprocess OF PROJECT testQtForiOS WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

PhaseScriptExecution Qt\ Qmake testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Qt\ Preprocess.build/Script-5E618435888B9D49F8540165.sh
cd /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug
/bin/sh -c \"/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Qt\ Preprocess.build/Script-5E618435888B9D49F8540165.sh\"
make[2]: `testQtForiOS.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj' is up to date.

PhaseScriptExecution Qt\ Preprocessors testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Qt\ Preprocess.build/Script-7EF0942E79C014DCEC8976BC.sh
cd /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug
/bin/sh -c \"/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Qt\ Preprocess.build/Script-7EF0942E79C014DCEC8976BC.sh\"
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `preprocess'.

=== BUILD TARGET testQtForiOS OF PROJECT testQtForiOS WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Create product structure
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.app

ProcessInfoPlistFile Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.app/Info.plist Info.plist
cd /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug
builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Info.plist -genpkginfo /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -o /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.app/Info.plist

CompileC testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/testQtForiOS/main.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/testQtForiOS.hmap -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang/ios -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include/QtWidgets -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include/QtGui -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I. -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator -pipe -fvisibility=hidden -fpascal-strings -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-sign-conversion -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -Wno-conversion -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -fPIE -DDARWIN_NO_CARBON -DQT_NO_PRINTER -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.dia -c /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/testQtForiOS/main.cpp -o /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o

CompileC testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/mainwindow.o /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/testQtForiOS/mainwindow.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/testQtForiOS.hmap -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang/ios -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include/QtWidgets -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include/QtGui -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I. -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator -pipe -fvisibility=hidden -fpascal-strings -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-sign-conversion -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -Wno-conversion -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -fPIE -DDARWIN_NO_CARBON -DQT_NO_PRINTER -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/mainwindow.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/mainwindow.dia -c /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/testQtForiOS/mainwindow.cpp -o /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/mainwindow.o

CompileC testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/testQtForiOS.hmap -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang/ios -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include/QtWidgets -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include/QtGui -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I. -I../../../../../Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator -pipe -fvisibility=hidden -fpascal-strings -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-sign-conversion -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -Wno-conversion -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -fPIE -DDARWIN_NO_CARBON -DQT_NO_PRINTER -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/moc_mainwindow.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/moc_mainwindow.dia -c /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/moc_mainwindow.cpp -o /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/moc_mainwindow.o

PhaseScriptExecution Qt\ Prelink testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Script-3DA90DAE39A0C9D07C6F6B0F.sh
cd /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug
/bin/sh -c /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Script-3DA90DAE39A0C9D07C6F6B0F.sh

Ld Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.app/testQtForiOS normal i386
cd /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/plugins/platforms -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -L/Users/Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/lib -F/Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/testQtForiOS.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -headerpad_max_install_names -u _qt_registerPlatformPlugin -L/Users/Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/plugins/platforms -framework UIKit -L/Users/Shared/Qt/5.2.0/5.2.0/ios/lib -framework OpenGLES -lz -lm -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -lqios_iphonesimulator_debug -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreText -framework CoreGraphics -lQt5PlatformSupport_iphonesimulator_debug -lQt5Widgets_iphonesimulator_debug -lQt5Gui_iphonesimulator_debug -lQt5Core_iphonesimulator_debug -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/testQtForiOS_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.app/testQtForiOS

CpResource testQtForiOS.xcodeproj/Default-568h@2x.png Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.app/Default-568h@2x.png
cd /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug
builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/testQtForiOS.xcodeproj/Default-568h@2x.png /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.app

Touch Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.app
cd /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug
/usr/bin/touch -c /Users/johan/Documents/Tmp/QtForiOS/build-testQtForiOS-iphonesimulator_clang_Qt_5_2_0_for_iOS-Debug/Debug-iphonesimulator/testQtForiOS.app

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you show the compiler output you get in QtCreator?

Comment: I have the compiler output for you, just need to figure out how to format the posting properly.

Comment: I gave you the bounty since you offered your help, which is what I wanted to achieve with the bounty.

Comment: Fabian thanks! It was not necessary, I was not expecting it, the main thing was that the problem was solved for you. The only thing that annoys me is that I could have been able to save you some time if I thought about it a little faster. I have encountered the same problems in the past with not having updated the command line tools, but then it has been for native development, I got other symptoms.